# Longest Path with constraint

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

I am solving a problem where I have a directed acyclic graph (DAG) and each edge $(i,j)$ has 2 weights: the first weight is a distance from $i$ to $j$ ($d(i,j)$), the second weight is a "gain" that is obtained by going from $i$ to $j$ ($g(i, j)$).
Now, the problem is to find a path $P$ from node $s$ (start) to node $d$ (destination) such that it maximize the gain (the sum of $g(i, j)$ for all $(i,j) \in P$) and the traveled distance (the sum of $d(i,j)$ for all $(i,j) \in P$) is not greater than a threshold D.

I know that longest path on a DAG is solvable in polinomial time, but the fact that the longest path it is not always admissible (when the traveled distance is > D) I can not find a solution.
Do you have any ideas how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I do not know if this comment is even relevant. On a sphere the shortest and longest paths between two points are parts of the same graph.

Comment: This can be solved with dynamic programming.

Answer (score 2):

Let $d_j(T)$ denote the distance of the longest path (with the best gain) from the source to node $j$, subject to the condition that the traveled distance in time does not exceed the threshold $T$, and let $A$ be the arc set of the graph. I slightly changed your notations: $d_{ij}$ denotes the length of arc $(i,j)$ (your gain that you want to maximize) and $t_{ij}$ denotes the extra resource, (the one for which you cannot exceed the threshold), in my case I assume it is time.

You can easily design a dynamic programming algorithm with the recursive equation:
$$
d_j(T)=\max\{d_j(T-1), \max_{k|(k,j)\in A}\{d_k(T-t_{kj})+d_{kj} \}\},
$$
with $d_s(0)=0$ (and $d_j(T)=-\infty$ for $T<0$).

The justification of this recursive equation is that to find the longest path from $s$ to $j$ without violating the extra constraint, you have two options:

1. Compute the longest path from $s$ to $j$ using one unit less of time
2. Compute the longest paths from $s$ to all predecessors $k$ of $j$ subject to the condition that the traveled time does not exceed $T-t_{kj}$, add the distance $d_{kj}$, and select the best path.

The optimal solution is the best path among these two.

Comment: Thank you! 
But I think your algorithm does't always find the optimal solution because you always take the arc if you do not exceed the threshold T. Take always the arc is not always the right choice. There may be arcs of "best gain" that I could not take them if I took all the previous ones.

However I have just read that my problem is called "Resource Constrained Shortest Path" and it is NP-hard.

Comment: I am pretty sure this algorithm is optimal. Actually the problem is weakly NP-hard, which is why this pseudo-polynomial algorithm can find the optimal solution. But you do have other options: linear programming will work fine if your graph is not too big. And if it is, the problem is a good candidate for lagrangian relaxation or column generation, with shortest path subproblems.